# Having trouble with EXtJS 3.4 tabpanel insert or add

Tags: extjs, insert, tabs

I am Using Extjs 3.4 I have created a tabpanel trying to insert code or add code is not working it shows that it is in the object but it does not show on the screen.  I have done doLayout to it as well.  I am using Ext.getCmp('tab0').add({code to put in}) maybe there is another way to do this. or I am way off track it will be a lot of code when run but I am doing it is the debug just to see if I can get something to work and I get nothing but going into the object Ext.getCmp('tab0') I see what I added or inserted and it looks fine I have items within items but it goes to where it should go but nothing shows on the screen.

If I am doing something that is not proper let me know.  I may end up putting it into the object and hiding it if I don't want it.

I expect it to work and show on the screen.

Comment: Please provide a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried render method? Perhaps you should look if your code doesn't have any issues, sometimes ExtJS does not load a component if there's something off.

Regardless, it would be nice to have a fiddle.

```
tabPanel.render([renderlocation]);
```